# got uploading twice when creating a new name with adding name from textbox and original file name using multer and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, multer

so, I just want to create name with adding name from textbox to the original file

script.js

```
angular.module('signin').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) 
{
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl, name){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append('name', name);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })

        .success(function(){
            console.log("uploaded");
        })

        .error(function(){
            console.log("fail to upload");
        });
}}]);

fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl, $scope.id);
```

and in the app.js

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: './upload/',
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, name + "_"+file.originalname)
   }
})
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/move', upload.single('file'), function(req,res,next){
    name = req.body.name;
    console.log('Uploade Successful ', req.file, req.body);
});
```

and the problem is the output from 'name' variable is always undefine in first time but around 2 second - 1 minutes, console update the log and show that the multer do an uploading file again with the 'name' variable has a value from the input . because of that, it's creating the unneeded file (it save the file twice, one is the unexpected file(the file with 'undefiene'in front of original name) and the file that I need), so how to fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem because of my configuration issues, Please check your configurations again, from my working code segment,

// create storage

```
var location_hotels = multer({ dest: './uploads/images' });
var cpUpload = location_hotels.fields([{ name: 'title', maxCount: 1 },
```

{ name: 'text', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'myfile', maxCount: 8 }]);

```
router.post('/upload_test', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files); // return if files exist
      console.log(req.files); // return if field exist
});
```

// upload data as form data, my angular service is,

```
angular.module('testServices', [])

.service('MyService', function($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, title, text, uploadUrl){
    var payload = new FormData();

    payload.append("title", title);
    payload.append('text', text);

    for(var x = 0; x<file.length; x++) {
        payload.append('myfile', file[x]);
    }

    console.log(payload);

    return $http({
        url: uploadUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: payload,
        //assign content-type as undefined, the browser
        //will assign the correct boundary for us
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
        //prevents serializing payload.  don't do it.
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    });
}
});
```

i guest it may help you.

// Or please change your code as below and try,

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res) { // get your post request
    profilePictures(req, res, function(err) { // do multer tasks
        if (err) {}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Was there something specific in the original poster's code/configuration that you can see needs changing?  It might help someone in the future if you can be specific as to what problem you have identified.  What specific thing did you change in your config (for example).